# TIME_TO_SEC is not working Correctly in mysql

Tags: mysql, time, sec

" select
SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(m.totalTime))) as totalDuration
from  m
inner join pd on pd.candidateId = m.candidateId
where m.s_id is not null
and pd.s = 1"

```
OUTPUT :totalDuration: 838:59:59

"select 
       (SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(m.totalTime))/3600)  as totalDuration 
from  m 
inner join pd on pd.candidateId = m.candidateId 
where m.s_Id is not null 
  and pd.s = 1"
```

Output:totalDuration:1207.7658

My question is why TIME_TO_SEC Function not returning  desire output
like in first query duration is  838:59:59 and in sec query by dividing 3600 it is shown different result  1207.7658(hr)

Comment: What is the desired output? If you can confirm that there is a bug in MySQL, please use their bug tracker

Answer (score 0):

Range of  SEC_TO_TIME()   is -838:59:59 to 838:59:59. So, when we are converting seconds to time if time is  greater than 838:59:59 it will always return 838:59:59 value in my case that is same issue .
so I have converted sec to hour by divided by 3600.

Comment: Please remove the parts of this answer that are not relevant to the question. It seems that some irrelevant content was copy-pasted from another source.

Answer (score 0):

`SEC_TO_TIME()` returns `'838:59:59'` if an argument is 3020399 **or greater**.

In your case the value of `SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(m.totalTime))` expression seems to be `4347957`. It is greater, so the function returns maximal value for TIME datatype.

But when you divide w/o convertion to TIME then the original value is used for division.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=43166d9756e68c60c9abdbf43136b340